# Authentication for Hadoop HTTP web-consoles ... via LDAP?

Tags: java, authentication, hadoop, ldap, hdfs

I want to limit access to the Hadoop web UIs. But I don't want to set up Kerberos. We have LDAP, though.

Looking around, I see:

1. [Authentication for Hadoop HTTP web-consoles](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html)
2. [Class LdapAuthenticationHandler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.2.2/hadoop-auth/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/security/authentication/server/LdapAuthenticationHandler.html)

I like to think I could somehow stuff the `LdapAuthenticationHandler` into the Web Authentication stuff, but it is not obvious, and I can not find an example.

Is what I am seeking possible?

Failing that, I could set up HTTP proxies that do basic auth via LDAP. If I do that, does the user ID information get relayed to the Hadoop web UIs? (I am thinking specifically of the HDFS file browser.)

Comment: Apache Knox project is designed for protecting most of the Hadoop APIs, otherwise, I've seen Nginx or Apache HTTPD reverse proxies used for doing the Auth

Comment: Also, if you are using Active Directory, that should already have Kerberos features you need